# C - remove students from an array(array of structure) except 10 with the highest average grade

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Hello everyone and thanks for taking your time to read this. I am practicing C and I have come upon an exercise I have not been able to solve for several days, no matter what I do.

The exercise says that I am given two structures `Student` and `Grade`. I am to create a function which accepts an array of students as a parameter and removes *all students except 10 with the highest average grade*. There are two restrictions: **I cannot create any arrays and I cannot sort the given array.**

**What I have tried**: I have created a for loop which iterates from **0** to **size-10** and to remove students one by one starting with the one with the lowest average grade, so in the end, I am left with 10 with the highest average grade.

I have auxiliary functions: **average** calculates the average grade of one student;

**index_lowest** finds the index of the student to be removed

the function **top_students** is the main function that does what the exercise says.

Here is my program:

```
struct Grade {
    char subject_name[100];
    int grade;
};

struct Student {
    char name[20], surname[20];
    int no_of_grades;
    struct Grade grades[100];
};

double average(struct Student s) {
    int i;
    double avg = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < s.no_of_grades; i++) {
        avg += s.grades[i].grade;
    }
    return avg / s.no_of_grades;
}

int index_lowest(struct Student students[], int size) { // returns the index of the student with the lowest avg
    double min = average(students[0]);

    int i, mini = 0; // mini is the index we search for

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (average(students[i]) < min) {
            min = average(students[i]);
            mini = i;
        }
    }
    return mini;
}

void top_students(struct Student students[], int size) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < (size - 10); i++) {
        int index = index_lowest(students, size);

        for (j = index; j < (size - 1); j++) {
            students[j] = students[j + 1];
        }
        size--;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit worrying that the top_students() function reduces the effective size of the array without communicating the new size to the caller.  I would have expected it to return the new, smaller size somehow....

Comment: What should happen if rank#10 and rank#11 have exactly the same average? (ties)

Comment: @johndoe: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 3):

The test of the outer loop of `top_student` is incorrect: you increase `i` and reduce `size` at each iteration, hence you stop too soon.

Here is simplified version:

```c
void top_students(struct Student students[], int size) {
    while (size > 10) {
        for (int j = index_lowest(students, size); j < size - 1; j++) {
            students[j] = students[j + 1];
        }
        size--;
    }
}
```

Note also that passing large structures by value is inefficient. Passing a pointer is much preferred. Computing `average()` just once per iteration is also advisable.

Here is a modified version:

```
double average(const struct Student *s) {
    int i, n;
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (i = 0, n = s->no_of_grades; i < n; i++) {
        avg += s->grades[i].grade;
    }
    return avg / n;
}

int index_lowest(const struct Student students[], int size) {
    // returns the index of the student with the lowest avegare
    // in case of ties, return the last index for the lowest average
    double min = average(&students[0]);
    int i, mini = 0; // mini is the index we search for

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        double avg = average(&students[i]);
        if (avg <= min) {
            min = avg;
            mini = i;
        }
    }
    return mini;
}
```

Comment: Yeah...I kept looking at that loop - there was something 'off' about it, but I couldn't see what:)

Comment: @chqrlie Hey thank you very much! I am very bad with using nested loops in the sense that I most of the time do not control them properly like in the example above. Thank you again I will be sure to study this thoroughly!

On another note though, what do you think of the idea I came up with to solve the problem? I could not think of anything else.

Comment: Your solution modifies the array and destroys its contents except for the 10 top students. You could instead swap the 10 best students at the beginning of the array, which is a partial sort, which is probably OK. `if (size > 10) { for (i = 0;  i < 10; i++) { swap(students, i, index_lowest(students + i, size - i); } }`. In this case, you would want `index_lowest` to return the lowest index for ties.